# My Eclipse/Ajax/MySQL/PHP doesnt work because the PHP file never seems to execute. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, html, ajax, eclipse

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110301-1815

PHPeclipse
net.sourceforge.phpeclipse.feature.feature.group
1.2.3.200910091456PRD

MySQL 5.1
MySQL-connector 5.1.13

Tomcat V 7.0.14

Tried to follow the example listed here: http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxphp.php

---

OK, so I start the Tomcat server.
I have a dynamic web project defined in Eclipse (contains example html and php files from tutorial) and I add that to the server.
Restart server html executes just fine.
I get to the open call for the php file and nothing happens.

---

Here are my questions in roughly their order of precedence  ...

1. If you were approaching writing a simple Ajax concept enabled website with a mysql database and developing on eclipse IDE, what tools/concepts would you use to accomplish this differently/better than the mix I describe above given a constraint of $0?
2. The examples I find on the web are not specific enough to my environment for me to follow the integration points very well.  I am unsure where the PHP file goes inside the dynamic web project folder structure nor how it is properly addressed/located by the html file calling it.
3. How can I tell when the PHP file executes?  Is it debuggable easily?

Comment: PHP doesnt run in Tomcat. (Unless you are using the PHP java bridge or Java based PHP runtime)

Answer (score 0):

first you should get a wamp server<"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP"> and link your website project workspace to the wamp server web root folder.

to you second question you might want to check this link out <"http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/25-resources-to-get-you-started-with-php-from-scratch/".

And to your third question you can debug php if you have xdebug installed. It comes prepackaged with some wamp server installations.

hope this answers your questions a bit